# Extracting multiple records from 2 tables in one row

Tags: sql

I need to extract datas from a first table, contening the codes, and then encode said codes with a second table.

The first table looks like:

TABLE1

| ID | Payment type | Country | Business Sector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 11111111 | 11111111 | 11111111 |
| 00002 | 22222222 | 22222222 | 22222222 |
| 00003 | 33333333 | 33333333 | 33333333 |

The second table looks like

TABLE2

| ID | Description | Type econde |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111 | Cash | Pay |
| 22222222 | Bank Transfer | Pay |
| 33333333 | Bank Check | Pay |
| 11111111 | Italy | Country |
| 22222222 | England | Country |
| 33333333 | USA | Country |
| 11111111 | First | Business |
| 22222222 | Second | Business |
| 33333333 | Third | Business |

The query I would need to extract is the following

| ID | Payment type | Country | Business Sector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Cash | Italy | First |
| 00002 | Bank Transfer | England | Second |
| 00003 | Bank Check | USA | Third |

If possible I would want to extract only 1 record selecting by the ID

| ID | Payment type | Country | Business Sector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00002 | Bank Transfer | England | Second |

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try joining the first table to the second one, thrice:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t2a.Descritption AS "Payment type",
    t2b.Description AS Country,
    t2c.Description AS "Business Sector"
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2a
    ON t2a.ID = t1."Payment type" AND t2a."Type econde" = 'Pay'
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2b
    ON t2b.ID = t1.Country AND t2b."Type econde" = 'Country'
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2c
    ON t2c.ID = t1."Business Sector" AND t2c."Type econde" = 'Business';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried for hours thinking I needed to use a pivot.
Instead it seems it was a lot easier.